# Как менять цену товара при смене его количества в корзине?

Tags: woocommerce

Работаю с woocommerce, прошу подсказать, как менять цену товара при смене его количества в корзине?

Сделал по этой статье, но ничего не сработало: https://misha.agency/woocommerce/dinamicheskie-czeny-tovarov.html?unapproved=7846&moderation-hash=14a1269fd669d3237020004054cb23ad#comment-7846

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
/* Автоматическое обновление корзины в зависимости от изменения количества товаров */
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
  if (is_cart()) :
   ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
           jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
           jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
        });
   </script>
<?php
endif;
}
```

Код нужно добавить в файл functions.php вашей дочерней темы.